# OSX Mail how to mark message as not junk

Tags: mail.app, icloud

I have some mail messages that OSX Mail puts in my junk folder but does not show the header saying  "Mail thinks this message is Junk Mail" and so does not show the button allowing me to mark the mail as not junk.

How do I get Mail to allow me to mark the mail as not junk.

These emails are put in the junk folder by me.com/iCloud so I would hope Apple would allow control via their apps.

Comment: Does control-clicking on the email, bring up a menu that would allow you to mark it as not junk?

Comment: @bassplayer7 - no it allows me to mark as Junk :(

Comment: Weird. Hopefully someone will have an answer. I'm curious on this one myself. It sounds like Mail handles email more locally then it should. I know it's not integrated with Gmail's junk mail system very well. Maybe it's the same with iCloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems iCloud is marking the message as junk using its algorithm. I don't believe you can adjust this from within the Mail.app. You will need to log into iCloud.com, enter Mail, find the particular message in your Junk Mail folder and then with the message selected, select the gear menu and you should be able to Mark as Not Junk.

To recap, as iCloud is flagging message as junk you must unflag message within iCloud.

Comment: Do you have any other junk mail filters or apps running, like SpamSieve? I'll try to update answer with images when I get back to my desktop and off iOS.

Comment: No the only filter is iCloud's

Comment: See edited answer. I think the "Mark as Not Junk" must be done from iCloud.com and can't be done from the app. Similarly Gmail spam shows up in Junk mail folder but not listed as junk/spam by Mail.app.

Comment: yes it can be fixed in iCloud - however not in Mail so is not the solution

Comment: I'll edit answer to remove parts about when Mail.app flags message as junk.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a tie between the server filtering of junk mail and the Mail client on the mac.

If this is troublesome, most people pick to disable the server side filtering and train the Mail client on their mac so that it can do all the marking and filing so you don't have this cognitive dissonance between a message that your local mail client "thinks is junk" and mail that sits in a folder that coincidentally is named junk.

Comment: How do you disable ICloud filtering?

Comment: @Mark I should have mentioned that server controls aren't viable specifically on iCloud. I think I was thinking of in general with other cloud providers.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while search for the same problem. My email provider was Gmail, but the iCloud idea tipped me off.

If there is **no brown banner on the email, Apple Mail did not mark it as junk/spam**, your email provider did.

In my case, it was a company email managed by Google Apps. So I logged into Gmail, went to the junk folder, and clicked the 'Not Spam' button on the emails. I did it for a few to train Gmail.

Comment: Yes I know this the question is can I set the junk or not for the server from the client? I expect the answer to be no for all but iCloud - but for iCloud being an Apple product I hope that there would be a way

Answer (score -2):

all you need to do in Mail toolbar is click on the thumbs up icon to the right of the trash bin.

Comment: Thius does not affect how iCloud marks a mail as junk - i.e. what happens if iCloud says the mail is junk - what can Mail.app do with it