# iCloud won't allow me to mark some mail as "Not Junk"

Tags: icloud, mail.app

I have a consistent issue of some legit emails showing up in my Mail client (OS X Mavericks) as junk.  They are also marked as junk in icloud.com which is why they are coming in as junk to my mail client.  The problem is, these emails can't be marked as "Not Junk" even in icloud.com.  I can mark them "Not Junk" and they will immediately be marked as junk again and reappear in my junk folder.

How can I get iCloud to accept that these messages are not junk and leave them set that way?

Comment: Are these emails sent to your `icloud.com` email address or to a 3rd-party email like yahoo?

Comment: to my icloud.com email.

Comment: For clarification, you said "these emails can't be marked as "not junk" even in icloud.com" but then said "I can mark them Not Junk and they will immediately be marked as junk again".  Are you correcting them according to [this Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202315)?

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing, what I mean is I set them as NOT junk but they instantly are marked junk again and reappear in the junk folder.  So in that sense I can't mark them as not junk, even though I can push the button.  Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Take a look at [these answers](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/196499/88313) and see if any help.  If so, we can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: That's actually my question, so no it doesn't help.  It helped at that time for a few specific emails, but the problem in this question is what to do about other emails that absolutely will not mark as junk no matter what I do within icloud.com.

Comment: You might be stuck with contacting Apple Support.

Comment: Have you tried manually dragging them to the inbox instead of clicking Not Junk? Beyond that, you would need to contact [iCloud Support](http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't do anything either.  The messages reappear in junk within a few seconds.  Contacting Apple support has never been any help at all when I encounter obscure issues like this, so I think I'm just stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a real solution!  If I save the sender of any of these "problem" emails to my address book within iCloud, then they are automatically not marked as Junk any longer.  Hooray!

Simply open the mail, click on the address of the sender, and click Save.  Problem solved once and for all!