# Mail.app is pushing all my mails to junk mail

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app

Mail.app puts all of my mail into the junk mail folder. Junk mail filtering is turned off. I have also turned off junk mail filtering on the server side and turned off all sorting rules. This only happens on one user account on my computer, Mail.app behaves normally in the other user. Every day I have to select all junk mail and drag it to my inbox and then waste my time manually sorting.

How can I completely reinstall Mail.app and still retain my accounts and mailboxes? mail app version 10.3 osx 10.12.6

Difference compared to the link being mentioned:
my mails are getting that brown colour clearly telling that they have been considered as junks, without my consent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Legit email is consistently going to junk folder despite NOT being marked as junk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196499/legit-email-is-consistently-going-to-junk-folder-despite-not-being-marked-as-jun)

Comment: the problem is I am having two users on my Mac. On user A, the mail.app is working perfectly fine. While on User B, mail.app is giving me serious troubles. through searches I have only found that I will need to reset Mac mail from the beginning. But what about my mails and the accounts being configured? Can I somehow back them all to some place without losing any info?

Comment: update to my issue: it has been resolved.

Comment: used Mail Backup X to backup those mails to my external drive. drained out every single bit from the Mail application. Rebooted the system, and reconfigured the mail application with the same credentials. now that is doing totally fine.

Comment: It would be great if you can add your solution as an answer instead of a comment.  That would help others who might have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used Mail Backup X to backup those mails to my external drive. drained out every single bit from the Mail application. Rebooted the system, and reconfigured the mail application with the same credentials. now that is doing totally fine.
I had downloaded it from here:http://www.mailbackupx.com/download.html